# Shortcut for pattern matching on same value-key name in Elixir map

Tags: elixir

I do a fair amount of pattern matching in this style:

```
def action(%{start_date: start_date, amount: amount, notify: notify %}) do
  # some action
end
```

Most of the times, the name I choose for the parameters are the same name in the map. Is there a shortcut of specifying that pattern matching case without repeating the same name for the key and the value ?

Something in the line of this pseudo code:

```
def action(%{start_date: %s, amount: %s, notify: %s}) do
  IO.inspect(start_date)
  # some action
end
```

Comment: In my humble opinion this saves some characters but introduces a certain amount of implicitness. That may not be obvious at that single example you are giving, but with more and more of such implicitness the code gets hard to read and more indirect thinking is required. Keep code explicit and pay the price of additional characters.

Comment: @smoes the definition of “indirect thinking” depends on what is “direct” for you and what your habits are. Sometimes when it comes to many map members to be explicitly matched, it becomes noisy and requires more “indirect reading.” I never used any shortage/syntactic sugar for that, but I could easily think of cases, where it makes much sense. E.g. [`Stream`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.4.4/lib/elixir/lib/stream.ex#L103-L120) module declares a bunch of macros with the single purpose: to shut down the noise in functions’ definitions.

Comment: FYI, https://github.com/whatyouhide/short_maps accomplishes something like this with a `~m` sigil.

Comment: @mudasobwa i totally agree with parts of your post. It sometimes helps to hide some details to be declarative and more explicit. The example `whatyouhide` postet e.g. implements something that is very intuitive when used in matchings using assignment. One can somehow guess, whats happening. In function declarations I would have to look it up and or google to find out, what it does. That's a point where I am willed to accept some code-noise instead.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is nothing out of the box, but one could simply create a macro for themselves to serve that purpose:

```
defmodule M do
  defmacro struct(params) do
    {:%{}, [], Enum.map(params, fn e -> {e, {e, [], Elixir}} end)}
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  require M # to use macro
  def action(M.struct([:a, :b]) = params),
    do: IO.inspect params, label: "Params are"
end

Test.action(%{a: 42, b: :ok})
#⇒ Params are: %{a: 42, b: :ok}
Test.action(%{a: 42})
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Test.action/1
```

The code above is of course just an MCVE, you probably need to enhance it somehow to handle corner cases more gracefully (and, probably, to have the more explicit readable macro that behaves smarter than just spitting the AST out, and considers the binding, etc,) but I believe that explains the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I introduced a sigil, `~m{...}`, to achieve destructing assignment.

```
~m{foo bar} = %{foo: 1, bar: 2}
foo  #=> 1
bar  #=> 2
```

Here's how I implement the sigil

```
defmodule DestructingAssignment do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do: import unquote(__MODULE__)
  end

  defmacro sigil_m({:<<>>, _line, [string]}, []) do
    spec = string
           |> String.split
           |> Stream.map(&String.to_atom/1)
           |> Enum.map(&{&1, {&1, [], nil}})
    {:%{}, [], spec}
  end
end
```

**Usage**

```
defmodule Foo do
  use DestructingAssignment

  def foo(~m{bar}) do
    # Do whatever you want with bar
    IO.inspect(bar)
  end
end

Foo.foo(%{bar: 1, baz: 2})
1
```

Comment: Why would you alias `import` with `use`? What’s wrong with explicit `import DestructingAssignment`? This looks a bit misleading, although it saves 3 chars in typing :)

Comment: Because otherwise you have to `require DestructingAssignment` (because the sigil is a macro, not a function) then `import DestructingAssignment`. `use` will implicitly `require` the module first.